# Efficient way to check character encodable by Font

Tags: pdfbox

What is the efficient way to check whether character is encodable by a font or not? We are generating PDF and text can contain foreign character. This require to check character by character whether its encodable by font or not.

At present I am using `PDFont.encode` to check but here font need to load in a document and seems like not a memory efficient.

PDFBox version: 2.0.9

Comment: *"This require to check character by character whether its encodable by font or not."* - But some code eventually will have to check character by character. Whether that's some code inside of PDFBox or your code, doesn't necessarily make a difference as far as efficiency is concerned.

Comment: Thanks @mkl. I have font1 (default), font2, font3 and font4 and I check character with fonts in that order. If font2 and font3 are not able to encode a character but font4 is able to encode then I cannot close PDFont and free memory but if its TrueTypeFont which can be closed. The issue is font2 and font3 are not used in document but still loaded until document get closed.

Comment: I don't see a pdfbox internal implementation of those checks being more memory efficient. It's actually the other way around, you could pre-parse the fonts, extract the information on available glyphs,  and close the fonts again. Using these information you could do your checks and only load a font again if it actually is needed.

Answer (score 1):

you can check which characters in your text have supported glyphs in a font set, as follows:

```
public boolean isFontSupported(PDType0Font font, String text) {
    try {
        int offset = 0;
        while (offset < text.length()) {
            int codePoint = text.codePointAt(offset);
            int gid = font.codeToGID(codePoint);
            if (gid == 0) {
                return false;
            }

            offset += Character.charCount(codePoint);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception swallow) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: `org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont` does not have a method `codeToGID` according to this java doc page:  https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/font/PDFont.html     Any idea what to use instead?